# Initializing gesture from continuous input (computer vision multitouch "click")

Tags: touch-screen, gestures

I asked a [similar question awhile back](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16138), but not exactly the same.

I have some multitouch hardware (Microsoft Kinect) that tracks the user in realtime. What is the best technique for initiating a gesture? There is no touch down/touch up - if the hand/joint is being tracked, it's "touched down".

I'm thinking a short downward stroke. Note that detecting joint size/shape is unavailable in this implementation.

Comment: I've never heard of a Kinect or any similar system being referred to as "multitouch". You might have more luck referring to it as "gestural UI" or "natural UI" (although the latter term often *encompasses* multitouch interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

Is it not worth using the existing gestures that Microsoft have established for the Kinect on the Xbox?

To "click" on something using Kinect on the Xbox, the app shows an "open hand" cursor. When you hover over an item you want to select, a progress ring shows up around the cursor. If you leave your hand over the same item for the entire duration of a "circle", the item is selected and you move on.

[Microsoft have a nice, comprehensive rundown of the Kinect gestures including videos on their website](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/kinect/body-tracking/body-controller).

Comment: Alas, unsupported bu relevant software.

Comment: @JoeStavitsky: are you saying that you can't emulate that interaction design easily enough? I haven't played with the Kinect SDK at all, but it looks to me that [Microsoft provides this control (what they call "HoverButtons") in the SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2011/08/16/kinect-sdk-for-windows-hover-button-hover-control.aspx)

Comment: I found the MS SDK quite sad, performance wise. I may re-evaluate it at a later date but I'm sticking with nite for now, and a relatively limited subset thereof.

Comment: I will look into the emulation suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Kinect for Windows SDK you can find information on creating gestures at the following two links:

http://blog.exceptontuesdays.com/post/27989563563/gestures-with-microsoft-kinect-for-windows-sdk-v1-5

http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/

I wrote the first blog post and have continued to use the library for some time.  Several of the Xbox gestures are already supported (per another answer here) and it is easy to design your own (using the package from either link).

Comment: Extremely tasty, will study more after semester ends

Comment: Good luck!  I do visit here, but also follow the "Kinect" tag (amount other NUI tags) at stackoverflow.com, if you need to ask more questions.